# What is the difference between options and choices in select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the requirements for a select method in a form are:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

So what is the difference between 'choices' and 'options'? I am trying to get to the html_options, but it says I need to fill in options first. I've been searching through the docs for half an hour and can't find anything on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choices can be a flat collection or a nested collection (this will generate optgroup tags). An example out of the docs:

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.pluck(:name, :id), {include_blank: 'None'})
```

You will always need to give in the arguments in the right order, incase you don't want to provide them you can simply pass in the default

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.pluck(:name, :id), {}, {required: true})
```

Anything you pass in html_options will be placed on the HTML tag, possible things you can pass:

- name: determined by rails if blank
- id: determined by rails if blank
- multiple: Specifies if multiple values can be selected
- required: Indicate that the field is required
- disabled: If the field is disabled
- size: How many items to show in the select (default 1)

---

The official documentation you are looking for is found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html